# dangrossman's bootstrap-daterangepicker date change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Using the [bootstrap-daterangepicker from dangrossman](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker). Does anyone know the best method to implement an "on date change" event which I can listen to? Because there seems to only be an on apply or on widget hide event, I want to update what is happening in real time.

Here is my existing code which has a callback function when I click apply / leave the date picker:

```
this.$el.find(".datepicker").daterangepicker(
             {
                opens: "left",
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                startDate: me.startDate,
                endDate: me.endDate,
                minDate: me.minDate,
                maxDate: me.maxDate,
                locale: {
                    applyLabel: 'Save'
                },
                showDropdowns: true,
                ranges: {
                    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
                    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
                    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
                    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                    'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
                }
            },
            function(start, end, label) {
                // Update Change Selection upon date widget close

                var startDate = new Date(Date.parse(start._d));
                var endDate = new Date(Date.parse(end._d));

                me.startDate = startDate;
                me.endDate = endDate;

                if (me.parent) {
                    me.parent.changeSelection(me);
                }
            }
        );
```

Thanks.

Comment: Whenever you are asking doubts regarding a third party plugin, please include the link to developer page.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$('#yourinputid').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log('changed');
});
```